# use define name in excel in dax formula

Tags: dax, excel-2016

i have  names defined in excel 2016 worksheet can  i use them in a Measure ( dax formula data model)

```
A+:=CALCULATE(COUNT(marks[Final Degree]),FILTER(marks, [Final Degree]>=AP_h))
```

where AP_h is a define name in the sheet

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try yourself by clicking the named cell and menu PowerPivot > Add to Data Model

Comment: My question mr.Olson how i can use define name in dax formula like AP_h